# How to solve ServiceNotFoundException in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, jwt

Error

```
 ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php 
 The service "token_authenticator" has a dependency on a non-existent service "lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_encoder".
```

what i need

- i need to validate angular2 app with symfony.

config.yml

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/private.pem'
public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/public.pem'
pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
token_ttl: 3600
```

security.yml

```
 firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        stateless: true

        guard:
            authenticators:
                - 'token_authenticator'
```

services.yml

```
 services:

 token_authenticator:
    class: AcmeStoreBundle\Security\TokenAuthenticator
    arguments: ['@lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_encoder', '@doctrine_mongodb']
```

routing.yml

```
 acme_store_login_user:
   type: rest
   path:     /login_check
   defaults: { _controller: AcmeStoreBundle:Login:login }
name_prefix:  api_
```

Login controller code

```
  public function loginAction(Request $request) {

   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $userName = $data['username'];
    $password = $data['password'];

    $user = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
            ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:User')
            ->findOneBy(['username' => $userName]);

    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }

    $isValid = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
            ->isPasswordValid($user, $password);

    if (!$isValid) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException();
    }

    $response = new Response(Response::HTTP_OK);
    $token = $this->getToken($user);

    $response = new Response($this->serialize(['token' => $token]), Response::HTTP_OK);
    return $this->setBaseHeaders($response);
}


public function serialize($data) {
    $context = new SerializationContext();
    $context->setSerializeNull(true);

    return $this->get('jms_serializer')
                    ->serialize($data, 'json', $context);
}

public function getToken(User $user) {

    return $this->container->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder')
                    ->encode([
                        'username' => $user->getUsername(),
                        'exp' => time() + 3600 ,
    ]);
}
```

refrence:

https://github.com/chalasr/lexik-jwt-authentication-sandbox
   https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest4/create-json-web-token#play

- can any one suggest how can i solve this problem.

Comment: which version of LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle are you using?

Comment: as you can see i have taken refrence from above link given above ver 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the 2.x version, where (as you can see from the changelog) the `lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_encoder` service (from the 1.x version) is no more. You should use `lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder.default`:

> The service lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_encoder has been removed in
>   favor of lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder.default that supports
>   OpenSSL and phpseclib crypto engines.

```
 token_authenticator:
    class: Acme\StoreBundle\Security\TokenAuthenticator
    arguments: ['@lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder.default', '@doctrine_mongodb']
```

Comment: now im having new problem Attempted to load class "TokenAuthenticator" from namespace "AcmeStoreBundle\Security".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: post the `AcmeStoreBundle/Security/TokenAuthenticator.php` file

Comment: i have upload full file url http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06840239099356572314

Comment: you're using the wrong namespace. also, paste the code in your question.

Comment: can you suggest in code snippet its about entity manager orm:mysql.but i need mongo db so tried like     and  use DoctrineMongoDB;  public function __construct(JWTEncoderInterface $jwtEncoder, DoctrineMongoDB $em)
    {
        $this->jwtEncoder = $jwtEncoder;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

Comment: that's is another question that deserve another answer

Comment: HI fed i have added new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094093/how-to-use-object-manager-in-symfony3 regard object manager

Comment: Thanks mate ! It helped me

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with *Symfony 4*, because My LoginConroller extends BaseController, So make sure your LoginController extends the *Controller* *Class* . Like This :

```
class LoginController extends Controller {
  .......
```

}